# Return cells with values in a column when we change the date on a different sheet and remove blank cells

Tags: worksheet-function

I have one excel sheet which I normally record the expenses everyday. Column 1 will contain the money a person is given and Row 1 will contain the date of the month. What will keep on changing is the amounts that you give every person. On some days I don't give some persons money meaning the cells are blank. In summary it looks like this
        `A             B               C
1       01/05/2015  02/05/2015  03/05/2015
2   Jack    2000      500            400
3   Mark    600                     7000
4   Martin           7000

5   James   5000                    6000
6   Daniel  7000

7   Elgon            6000`

On worksheet 2
When I type in 1/5/2015 on one cell in worksheet, I would like it to return something like this:
        
         `A        B
1       Date    01/05/2015
2       Jack     2000
3       Mark      600
4       James    5000
5       Daniel   7000`
 
If I change the date to 3/5/2015, I would like it to return
   
      `A         B
1   Date    03/05/2015
2   Jack     400
3   Mark    7000
4   James   6000`
I don''t want to see the blank cells without any amounts.